# How can create dublicate user type in Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel

When ı add the user, automatically added one userType so, I want to add one more user type.

I added userType like this:

```
$startLevel = FortuneTypeLevelRepository::instance()->getFirstLevel(FortuneType::COFFEE);
        UserFortuneTypeRepository::instance()->create([
            'user_id'         => $user->id,
            'fortune_type_id' => $startLevel->fortune_type_id,
            'percentage'      => $startLevel->percentage,
            'price'           => $startLevel->price,
            'credit'          => $startLevel->credit,
            'star'            => $startLevel->star,
            'max_busy'        => $startLevel->max_busy,
            'can_express'     => $startLevel->can_express,
            'express_price'   => $startLevel->price,
            'express_credit'  => $startLevel->credit,
        ]);


        Cache::forget('fortuneTellerList.' . $startLevel->fortune_type_id);
```

How can ı duplicate this userType only one changes like this:

```
$startLevel = FortuneTypeLevelRepository::instance()->getFirstLevel(FortuneType::TAROT);
```

One type `COFFE` one type `TAROT`, I want to add this two user type when ı create a user?

Comment: What does the `getFirstLevel()` function do?
What is the purpose of clearing the item from the Cache?